# Playing a sequence of sounds causes force close

Tags: android, multithreading, audiotrack

I am creating an application that plays musical notes when you press a series of buttons on the screen.  There is also a button that will play back a series of notes (up to 10 notes) when it is pressed.  The application works fine at first.  However, if you have a series of notes to play and you press the playback button several times consectively the application will eventually force close.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private final int duration = 1; // seconds 
private final int sampleRate = 10000; 
private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate; 
private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples]; 
private double freqOfTone; // hz 

private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

 public void onPlayButtonClick(View v){
    playMultiNoteSound();
}
synchronized void playMultiNoteSound(){

    CharSequence chrs1;
    TextView lblNoteList;
    lblNoteList=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblNoteList);
    chrs1=lblNoteList.getText();

    for(int i=0;i<chrs1.length();i++){
        final int int1=i;

        Thread thrdPlay=new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );
                audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize, 
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                char chrCurrent;
                CharSequence chrs;


                TextView lblNoteList;
                lblNoteList=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblNoteList);
                chrs=lblNoteList.getText();
                chrCurrent=chrs.charAt(int1);
                Double[]allTones;
                allTones= new Double[chrs.length()];
                allTones[int1]=getToneForText(chrCurrent);
                byte[] results;
                results=genSelectTone(allTones[int1]);
                audioTrack.write(results, 0, results.length);
                audioTrack.setStereoVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                audioTrack.play();
                if(audioTrack.getPlayState()==AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_STOPPED){
                    audioTrack.stop();
                    audioTrack.release();
                }
            }
        });
        thrdPlay.setDaemon(true);   
         thrdPlay.start();
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(thrdPlay!=null){
            thrdPlay.stop();
            thrdPlay=null;
        }
        }

}
public double getToneForText(char val){
    Float dblResult;
    dblResult=0f;
    switch (val){
    case '1':
        dblResult=261.63f;
        break;
    case '2':
        dblResult=293.66f;
        break;
    case '3':
        dblResult=329.63f;
        break;
    case '4':
        dblResult=349.23f;
        break;
    case '5':
        dblResult=392.0f;
        break;
    case '6':
        dblResult=440.0f;
        break;
    case '7':
        dblResult=493.88f;
        break;
    case '8':
        dblResult=523.25f;
        break;
    case '9':
        dblResult=587.33f;
        break;
    case '0':
        dblResult=659.26f;
        break;
    }       
    return dblResult;
}
```

I believe that is all of the relevant code.  Please let me know if you need additional information/code.

Comment: If there's a force close there will be a stack trace of the exception which causes it. Post the logcat output.

Comment: Aside from what @Squonk suggested (which you should do), you may also consider looking up how to read a logcat. It will save you from having to ask a new question each time your app throws an `Exception`.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I have used LogCat.  The error is as follows:  obtainBuffer track disabled, restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not re-initialize `audioTrack` for every iteration. Instead initialize it before loop and use `audioTrack.write` in a loop. You are simply re-initialing it without filling its buffer.

Secondly, just as an offer u should not update gui and play a sound in same thread. Try to use `AsyncTask` instead.